# How to display all types of an object (in Scala)?

Tags: scala, reflection, types

With the `isInstanceOf` method, one can check the type of an object. For example:

```
scala> val i: Int = 5
i: Int = 5

scala> val a: Any = i
a: Any = 5

scala> a.isInstanceOf[Any]
res0: Boolean = true

scala> a.isInstanceOf[Int]
res1: Boolean = true

scala> a.isInstanceOf[String]
res2: Boolean = false
```

How can one display all types of an object (if it is possible at all ?) ?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this pretty easily in 2.10 (M4 or later):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def superTypes(t: Type): Set[Type] =
  (t.parents ++ t.parents.flatMap(superTypes)).toSet

def allTypes[A](a: A)(implicit tag: TypeTag[A]) = superTypes(tag.tpe) + tag.tpe
```

Which gives us the following:

```
scala> allTypes(1).foreach(println)
AnyVal
Any
NotNull
Int

scala> allTypes("1").foreach(println)
String
Any
Object
Comparable[String]
CharSequence
java.io.Serializable

scala> allTypes(List("1")).foreach(println)
scala.collection.LinearSeq[String]
scala.collection.GenSeq[String]
scala.collection.IterableLike[String,List[String]]
scala.collection.GenIterable[String]
scala.collection.GenTraversableLike[String,Iterable[String]]
...
```

You'll have a much harder time trying to do anything like this pre-2.10.

Comment: Thank you, with 2.10 it looks indeed pretty easy. Do you know if it is possible at all to list all types in pre-2.10 ?

Comment: [Manifests](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/Manifest.html) aren't really designed to support this kind of thing. You could use the [Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to get superclasses, implemented interfaces, etc., but that's very different from getting the _types_.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution, which makes use of the `baseType` method to reify the type parameter.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def typesOf[T : TypeTag](v: T): List[Type] =
  typeOf[T].baseClasses.map(typeOf[T].baseType)
```

Example:

```
scala> typesOf("1") foreach println
String
CharSequence
Comparable[String]
java.io.Serializable
Object
Any
```

Comment: `baseClasses` is handy, but those aren't _types_, of course, which is what the question asked for. It's also worth noting that this won't work pre-2.10.

Comment: @TravisBrown The question says _display_ all types. What `baseClasses` returns are the `Symbol` for the types. You can call `asTypeSymbol` on all of them, or, of course, `.asType` or `.typeSignature`.

Comment: But say for example that you want the types of `List("1")` such that you could know whether `GenSeq[String]` is one of them (without using `isInstanceOf` for whatever reason). Once you've used `baseClasses` there's no way to get that information—all you can do is get the type symbol for `GenSeq`.

Comment: Note though, for example, that `typesOf(Seq(1)) contains typeOf[collection.TraversableLike[Int, Iterable[Int]]]` is false, although that's definitely one of its types.

Comment: @TravisBrown I'm pretty sure it contains `TraversableLike[Int, Seq[Int]]`.